# Pointers with multidimensional arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

i have a function that generates randomize numbers between 0 and 2,and i want to use pointers but anyway i could not executed it.
First i generate randomize number and then i want to print the multidimensional array to see what it has generated
i just want to assign randomized number to an array(with using pointers) and then print them using pointers again

```
int **RandomizedMatrix; //integer multidimensional array        
int ***AdressOfMatrix =  &RandomizedMatrix; //assigning the adress of matrix to an integer pointer

void RandomizedMatrixGenerator(int LineNumber,int ColumnNumber,int ***AdressOfMatrix)
{            
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<LineNumber*ColumnNumber; i++)
    {
        **AdressOfMatrix = rand()%2;        
    }
    for (i=0; i<LineNumber; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<ColumnNumber; j++) 
        {                    
           printf("%d",***(AdressOfMatrix+i)+j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what help you want other than being told that you are right, you need to learn how to use pointers. I'm sure if you punch "pointers C" into a search engine you'll find lots of pages about them. (Hint: You have to make them point to something.)

Comment: Do you have a specific question about pointers? That's a big topic.

Comment: i just want to assign randomized number to an array(with using pointers) and then print them using pointers again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what i understand is right you want to fill your 2 dimensional array with 1s and 0s so you can do that

```
    void randmtrgen(int row,int column,int **mtr){
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<row;i++){
        for (j=0;j<column;j++){
            mtr[row][column]=rand()%1+1;
            }
        }
    }
```

That will fill your matrix as you wish and i suggest you to not use dereference operator if you are not good with it square brackets mostly fine.
And if you have an urge to use dereference operator you can use that line

```
    *(*(mtr+row)+column)=rand()%1+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you want to assign random numbers you need two `for()` loops:

```
for (i=0; i<LineNumber*ColumnNumber; i++)
{
     **AdressOfMatrix = rand()%2;
}
```

All this is going to do is assign `LineNumber*ColumnNumber` number of times the first element of your matrix a number. If you want to do it this way, you need to increment the rows and columns while assigning.

Also your "random" number isn't going to be random because you didn't seed it. Here's an example of what you wanted to do:

```
  srand((unsigned) time(NULL));  // Seed the random number generator

  for(row = 0; row<LineNumber; row++){
     for(col = 0; col<ColumnNumber; col++){
        ran = rand()%100;           // Generate a randome numer 1-99
        *(*(matrix+row)+col) = ran; // assign a random number to the element
     }
  }

  for(row = 0; row<LineNumber; row++) {
      for(col = 0; col<ColumnNumber; col++){
         printf("[%d]", *(*(matrix+row)+col));  //Display the random number
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
```

So given a 4x3 matrix, you could get an output like:

```
[99][33][38]
[59][2][28]
[50][39][2]
[85][45][99]
```